# Does using virtual methods violates LSP( L part of SOLID principles) or there are some exceptions?

Tags: design-principles, liskov-substitution-principle, solid-principles

Does using **virtual** methods violates **LSP**( L part of **SOLID** principles) or there are some exceptions?

Thanks in advance,
Saghar Ayyaz

Comment: Can you post an example? In particular one that you think may be an LSP violation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that? Virtual methods in themselves are just a mechanism for polymorphism. The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is a just constraint on how you implement the overrides (and other aspects of descendant classes) in order to get predictable polymorphic behaviour.